# Display Wordpress posts of only one category

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I am trying to display Wordpress posts of only one category called news on my page... However I can't seem to make it work, it still displays all posts. Any idea what I am doing wrong? The code is

```
<?php
 $postslist = get_posts('category=news&numberposts=10000&order=DESC&orderby=date');
 foreach ($postslist as $post) :
    setup_postdata($post);
 ?>
 <li>
 <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
 <br><span class="caption"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')) ?></span>
 </li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You try to get the **category by name**.

But your code is not correct for this method.

Try this:

```
$postslist = get_posts('category_name=news&numberposts=10000&order=DESC&orderby=date');
```

Or use the category ID to get your results:

```
$postslist = get_posts('category=1&numberposts=10000&order=DESC&orderby=date');
```

You can read more about `get_posts` here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts